# What is wrong with this MySQL/Java prepared statement syntax?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, web-applications, jdbc

I have a small program that I have built to cycle a list of passwords from a database, hash them, and update the database with the hashed password. I have already altered the column length so as to be sure that the password didn't come in to long. I then wrote this into my method that is supposed to write the values to the database.

```
    sqlInsert = "UPDATE dealers SET Password = ?, Password2 = ?, PasswordID = ? WHERE DNo = ?";
    PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);
    statement.setString(1, pw2);
    statement.setString(2, pw1);
    statement.setString(3, pId);
    statement.setString(4,  dId);
    result = statement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);
```

The problem is that every time I run the program I get the following error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, Password2 = ?, PasswordID = ? WHERE DNo = ?' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in     your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version     for the right syntax to use near '?, Password2 = ?, PasswordID = ? WHERE DNo =         ?' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorA    ccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1755)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1679)
    at     com.secureautodata.business.data.KeyGenerator.encInsert(KeyGenerator.java:99)
at com.secureautodata.business.data.KeyGenerator.main(KeyGenerator.java:392)
```

I have broken the syntax down and tried it in the database alone and it worked fine, is there something that I am missing in my prepared statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
result = statement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);
```

with

```
result = statement.executeUpdate();
```

The first method is defined in the base `Statement` interface and would execute the given SQL update string without the bound parameters. You need to use the one defined in `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Thanks man, I moved from not using prepared statements to using prepared statements because I couldn't judge what the next password was going to be without first seeing it, I must have just forgotten to remove it when I made the transition. As they always say 4 eyes are better than two, because I certainly overlooked that at least 10 times Thank you again very much